# Does chown command require login and logout to reflect changes?

Tags: permissions, chown, ownership

Does `chown` command require login and logout to reflect changes?

Comment: In general, no it doesn't. Is there something that isn't working for you related to chown?

Comment: Yes.. I used chown to change access permissions to a file. But I still cannot modify the file

Comment: You really should have asked a question about that then. As it is, this is an [X Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and to really get your problem solved you'll have to ask about the *real* issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not. Effect of `chown` command is applied immediately.

Answer (score 0):

If your in a desktop environment you should be able to right click on the file and then click on 'properties' option.  If you go to the permissions tab you can verify that your the owner and have 'Read and write' Access.

If the file is suppose to do something you can check the 'Execute' box.

Comment: How does this answer the question about whether `chmod` requires a logout/login?

Comment: You have already commented on the wording of the question and it sounds like Amruta is more interested in changing the permissions of the file than the actual chown command.  So I thought it would be better to provide some information that may help them resolve there issue.